# I am trying to animate the navigation bar on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which is meant to use jQuery so that when the 'Show navigation' button is clicked, that button will disappear, a 'Hide Navigation' button will appear, as will the Navigation options. The hope would be then that the 'Hide' button would do the opposite. I can get the show hide buttons to disappear and reappear accordingly, but the navigation options just stay in place.

Here is the code:

```js
var nav = function(){
     $('.navtoggle').click(function(){
      $('#navbar').animate({
       top:'10px'
       }, 200);
   
      $('.navtoggle').animate({
       top:'-40px'
       }, 200);
   
      $('.navexit').animate({
       top:'0px'
          }, 200);
     });

     $('.navexit').click(function(){
      $('#navbar').animate({
       top:'-40px'
       }, 200);
   
      $('.navtoggle').animate({
       top:'0px'
          }, 200);
   
      $('.navexit').animate({
       top:'-40px'
       }, 200);  
     });
    };
  
    $(document).ready(nav);
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
     <script type='text/javascript'       src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="navanimate.js"></script>
        <div id="top_container">
     <div id ="navbar">
     
         <a class="navigation" href="index.html"><p>Home</p></a> 
         <a class="navigation" href="CV.html"><p>CV</p></a> 
            <a class="navigation" href="Video.html"><p>Video</p></a>
            <a class="navigation" href="Hobbies.html"><p>My Hobbies</p></a>
            <a class="navigation" href="Coursework.html"><p>Coursework</p></a>
            <a class="navigation" href="Animation.html"><p>Animation</p></a>
       
 </div>
 <div class ="navtoggle">Show Navigation</div>
 <div class ="navexit">Hide Navigation</div>        
 
     <h1>Home Page</h1>
        
    </div>
    <div id="main_content">
     <p id="site_intro">Over the 6 pages of this website, I shall detail and exemplify everything I have learnt in the labs for the Introduction to Multimedia module. Browse and discover the many things I too have learnt over the last semester. <br><br>Throughout this site you will find many things, including my experience in the past, a short video of me, my favourite things to do, my work this term and the animation developed for the site. Enjoy!</p>
     <ul><h3>About Me</h3>
         <li>Candidate Number: 106244</li>
            
            <li>Course: Games and Multimedia Environments</li>
            <li>Year of Study: First year</li>
        </ul>
        
    <img src="images/IMG_0334.JPG" width="932" height="1142" alt="Good ol' picture of myself"/>
        </div> 
        <div id="social_links">
     <ul>Find Me Here
         <li><a href="http://facebook.com/easyfreddy"><img src="images/icons/Free-Shaded-Social-Icons/48/facebook-Icon.png" width="30" height="30" alt="My Facebook"/></a>Facebook</li>
            <li><a href="http://spoopy-freddie.tumblr.com/"><img src="images/icons/Free-Shaded-Social-Icons/48/Tumblr-Icon.png" width="30" height="30" alt="My tumblr Blog"/></a>Tumblr</li>
            <li><a href="http://therealfreddie.deviantart.com/"><img src="images/icons/Free-Shaded-Social-Icons/48/Deviantart-Icon.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/></a>DeviantArt</li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
    <div id="footer"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please post also the HTML, and if possible a working fiddle with your code to reproduce your work (www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Unless you need to support legacy browsers it's better to use css transition than jQuery animate

Comment: I am not quite sure how to put in the HTML. it doesn't seem to want to just show source code and formats it